# .NET Maui - Problem changing margin of custom control element during page load (for android deployment)

Tags: .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I'm trying to create a basic custom control to replace the stock maui progress bar that allows me to set a colour for the filled and unfilled portion of the bar.

I've created a simple control with two overlapping border elements and dependency properties that allow alteration of their background colour and a dependency property to set progress between zero and one. When the progress property is changed the 'progress' border right margin is altered accordingly.

XAML:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="MauiRIID.CustomProgressControl">
    <Grid>

        <Border x:Name="ProgressBarUnfilledBorder" />


        <Border x:Name="ProgressBarBorder" />
        
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

Code Behind:

```
public double? BorderMargin = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// The background colour of the border that represents the filled section of the progress bar.
    /// </summary>
    public Color ProgressColor
    {
        get => GetValue(ProgressColorProperty) as Color;
        set => SetValue(ProgressColorProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Bindable property for progress colour
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty ProgressColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ProgressColor), typeof(Color), typeof(CustomProgressControl),
        propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) =>
        {
            var control = (CustomProgressControl)bindable;

            control.ProgressBarBorder.Background = newvalue as Color;
        });

    /// <summary>
    /// The background colour of the border that represents the unfilled section of the progress bar.
    /// </summary>
    public Color ProgressBackgroundColor
    {
        get => GetValue(ProgressBackgroundColorProperty) as Color;
        set => SetValue(ProgressBackgroundColorProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Bindable property for unfilled background colour
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty ProgressBackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ProgressBackgroundColor), typeof(Color), typeof(CustomProgressControl),
        propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) =>
        {
            var control = (CustomProgressControl)bindable;

            control.ProgressBarUnfilledBorder.Background = newvalue as Color;
        });

    /// <summary>
    /// The progress bar progress expressed as a double from 0 to 1
    /// </summary>
    public double? Progress
    {
        get => GetValue(ProgressProperty) as double?;
        set => SetValue(ProgressProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Bindable property for progress indicator
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty ProgressProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Progress), typeof(double), typeof(CustomProgressControl), propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) =>
    {
        var control = (CustomProgressControl)bindable;

        double? progressValue = newvalue as double?;

        double? widthOfFilledProgressBar = control.ProgressBarUnfilledBorder.Width * (1 - progressValue);

        control.BorderMargin = (double)widthOfFilledProgressBar;

    });



    public CustomProgressControl()
    {
    InitializeComponent();

        LayoutChanged += CustomProgressControl_LayoutChanged;

    }

    private void CustomProgressControl_LayoutChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressBarBorder.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, (double)BorderMargin, 0);
    }
```

In the implementation, if I change the value of the control's Progress property after the form is loaded (e.g. through a bound button command), everything works as expected on both windows and android deployment.

However when I change the Progress property during a page load (specifically the LayoutChanged event using Maui community toolkit), the custom control updates the right margin of the progress border as it should in windows deployment but not in android deployment - the Progress property is set but no change is made to the appearance of the custom control and no errors are raised.

Implementation XAML:

```
ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:customControls = "clr-namespace:Inphys.MauiRIID"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="MauiRIID.SplashView"
             Title="SplashView"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="LayoutChanged"
            Command="{Binding TestCommand}">
        </toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior>
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>
    
    <Grid>
        
        <!-- Loading progress bar -->
        <customControls:CustomProgressControl x:Name="TestProgressBar" ProgressColor="Blue" ProgressBackgroundColor="Green" Progress="{Binding Progress}" Margin="100" />

    </Grid>
```

Implementation viewmodel:

```
 public class SplashPageViewmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Properties

        private double m_progress = 0;
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public double Progress
        {
            get
            {
                return m_progress;
            }
            set
            {
                if (m_progress == value)
                    return;

                m_progress = value;

                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Progress)));
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Events

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        #endregion

        #region Commands

        public ICommand TestCommand { get; set; }


        #endregion

        public SplashPageViewmodel()
        {
            TestCommand = new RelayCommand(Command_Test);
        }

        private void Command_Test()
        {
            Progress += 0.1;
        }

    }
```

I've tried binding TestCommand to each of the events of the ContentView class with no result. I've also tried calling InvalidateLayout() and InvalidateMeasure() within the custom control code after the the Progress property has been changed. I get the same problem whichever version of .Net and Maui community toolkit I use.

I've tested this on these [android emulators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWN3o.png)

My background is in WPF development, I'm new to android and I've never used used Xamarin forms before moving to Maui development, so sorry if I've missed something obvious.

Can anyone give me a clue what to change to make the android implementation work as it should? Am I missing something that I need to do specific to android deployment or is this a bug in Maui or the community toolkit?

Comment: What's the reason that you're implementing your own progress bar control (It's totally valid to do so)? There are some ready-made controls available on nuget.org. Apart from that, I wouldn't use Borders for this. You might want to check out [MAUI Graphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics) or [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp), I recommend the latter. I've written a short blog post about [custom controls with SkiaSharp](https://ewerspej.hashnode.dev/how-to-write-a-custom-control-for-net-maui-using-skiasharp).

Comment: Hi ewerspej, thanks for the reply. To be honest I'm just feeling my way with Maui at the moment with an eye on moving a WPF project to android and iOS. Coming from WPF and not knowing Xamarin I kind of assumed that I would be able to a control template in a similar way to WPF. Making a ContentView based control just seemed the next logical step. I'll definitely look at MAUI Graphics / Skiasharp. I was going to at some point to build a chart control but I thought a content view based control would be simpler - thanks for the link (and blog!) by the way, that looks perfect.